# Can Java act as a Named Pipes server?

Tags: java, windows, named-pipes

I know Java can act as a client for reading/writing named pipes, but I need another program which acts as a server.

In this case the program I am communicating with must act as the client, rather than the server.  Is it possible for Java to act in server mode for named pipes?

EDIT: In named pipes (Windows) there are client and server modes.  A server must first be established before a client can connect to it.  I have a legacy application which acts as a 'client', this means that it connects to what it assumes is an already established named pipe.
I have a new java application which I would like to have communicate with this legacy app using named pipes.  I have only found examples of how to use Java named pipes in connection to previously established named pipes.

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?  If there's something wrong, at least comment on why you downvote!

Comment: Java to act in server mode , please elaborate ??
Anyways I am not the downvoter , but will you give you an upvote to balance it :)

Comment: @RichieHindle Windows.

Comment: @Daisetsu: +1 from me; I can't explain the downvotes - it seems like a perfectly reasonable question (but I'm afraid I don't know the answer).

Comment: Yes, it can, but the question is whether the API is already out there. If there's no existing support, this is something that could be added with JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Well on linux and mac you can always have java emit to the console one line at a time.  Example:

In one terminal window to this:

```
 mkfifo myPipe
 java -jar mydataserver.jar > mkfifo
```

In a second terminal window do this:

```
 while read line; do echo "What has been passed through the pipe is \
 ${line}"; done<myPipe
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create named pipe on the Java server using JNA library https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

It is clearly shown in the following test: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32NamedPipeTest.java

API of JNA wrapper is the same as Win32 hence you will be able to use all the features and power of named pipes on Windows.